# ignore conf file during GIT pull

Tags: git

I have following files in git:

```
-com.src.java.blabla
-config
  conf.yaml
```

I want to update all the code in project with a pull request but not conf.yaml, because it has been modified to contain path to local machine.
My pulls are therefore rejected:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        conf.yaml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stash your local changes before pulling:

```
$ git stash
```

Now your working area is clean, and you can do the `git pull`.
Afterwards, do a `git stash pop` to merge your local changes back to your working area:

```
$ git stash pop
```

This has the advantage that it also properly considers upstream modifications in the files you modified locally and *merges* your local changes back.

Comment: To add to this, why is conf.yaml not in gitignore? You could have a conf_sample.yaml that contains the sample content and is checked into the repository so users can copy it to conf.yaml (that is gitignored) on their machine and fill in the right values. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: @Xatenev probably it is really part of the repository - depending on the environment, sometimes it is required to change certain files to get an application running. However, a better approach would certainly be to use some kind of template mechanism and only put the template itself into git ... on the other hand, it is then more difficult to get upstream changes back to the local file ... It's a tradeoff ;-)

Comment: @Xatenev that file is in repository, i cant ignore it

Comment: @JBoy what do you mean? `git rm -rf --cached` when you ignored it should work just fine.

Comment: @msanford quite simple see above

Comment: @Xatenev i mean that i cant add it to `.gitignore`

Comment: @JBoy Why can't you add it?

Comment: @Xatenev TIL! I didn't realize `--cached` would allow you to subsequently ignore it. I assumed you had to do [this](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/).

Comment: @Xatenev i can add `conf.yaml` in the `.gitignore` file. But a `git status` would still show the `conf.yaml` file as "to be committed" because its already known by repo (is in remote repo)

Comment: @JBoy Thats exactly where the command I posted above jumps in. It basically removes them from being tracked by the repository, see https://danielmiessler.com/blog/removing-files-from-a-git-repository-without-actually-deleting-them/

Comment: @msanford Yeah, the difference being one just removes them from being tracked but doesn't remove them from the history, where your link explains how to purge **sensitive** data entirely(including history) when they have accidently being committed.

Comment: @Xatenev pls put a reply instead of a comment, am gonna try out now, i think that if it works it would be a better solution, this way i dont need to remember to do stash/pull/pop all the times

Comment: @Xatenev Indeed, I thought that once it was known to the repo at all, including in past commits, it wouldn't be ignore-able. (I've never actually had to do it before.) Thanks for that!

Comment: @AndreasFester Can you add the `gitignore` part (possibly with a section on how to delete already checked in files (`git rm -rf --cached`))to your answer as requested by OP (JBoy)? I don't want to "steal" your answer.